# List of Figures and Other Listings as Section NOT Chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

How can I change the formatting for ALL listings (ie list of figures, list of tables, and other custom listings) So that the heading format is a section title, not a chapter title.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\chapterstyle{ell}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \listoffigures
    \clearpage
    \listoftables

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{A chapter}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
            \caption{some figure caption}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{table}[htbp]
            \caption{some table caption}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to redefine `chapter` temporarily via:

```
\let\chapterOld\chapter
\let\chapter\section
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
\let\chapter\chapterOld
```

But it doesn't work, think they are using starred versions or something.

Is there some setting for `memoir` that allows this to be defined?

Comment: `memoir` uses `\newlistof` to generate the `\listof...` commands -- this is totally different to the standard classes such as `book` etc. You can try to change the `\@namedef{lofheadstart}{...}` (see the `memoir` code for this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\chapterstyle{eli}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \bgroup
      \chapterstyle{article}
      \tableofcontents
      \clearpage
      \listoffigures
      \clearpage
      \listoftables
    \egroup

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{A section}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
            \caption{some figure caption}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{table}[htbp]
            \caption{some table caption}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah yeah. Basically that is exactly what I want, but the section headings for each listing are different from the custom format in the rest of the document.

Comment: How so?  \chapterstyle{article} specifies 9 parameters and \chapterstyle{eli} specifies 6.

Answer (score 2):

I see no other way than redefining `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. To obtain a consistent layout, define a command like

```
% \renewlistof{\listof...}{extension}{heading}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\renewlistof[3]%
   {\renewcommand#1%
      {\section*{#3}%
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#3}%
       \markboth{#3}{#3}%
       \@starttoc{#2}%
      }%
   }
\makeatother
\renewlistof\listoffigures{lof}{\listfigurename}
\renewlistof\listoftables{lot}{\listtablename}
```

The command assumes that a preceding `\newlistof{listoffigures}{lof}{\listfigurename}` etc. has set up whatever has to be set of for collecting the listing entries.